# Testing GreenDao Entities, QueryBuilder is always Null

Tags: android, junit, greendao

Im current trying to test a greenDao entity in android and i can not work out how to correctly get a copy of a dao object.

I am currently trying:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

    user = new User(id, userId, email, password, token);

    Context context = new MockContext();
    DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper openHelper = new DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper(context , null, null);
    SQLiteDatabase db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    daoSession = new DaoMaster(db).newSession();
    userDb = daoSession.getUserDao();

    assertNotNull(userDb); // This PASSES

    userDb.queryBuilder().list(); // This ALWAYS throws null pointer exception
}
```

Any suggestions? My test class extends `AndroidTestCase`

**UPDATE:**

I have worked out how to access the entities when running tests on a device using the following:

```
public class UserDaoHelperTest extends ApplicationTestCase<Application> {

    private UserDao userDb;

    public UserDaoHelperTest() {
        super(Application.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void setUp(){

        DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper openHelper = new DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper(getContext(), null, null);
        SQLiteDatabase db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        DaoSession daoSession = new DaoMaster(db).newSession();
        userDb = daoSession.getUserDao();
    }
}
```

Comment: daoSession.getUserDao() must be null try to check that.

Comment: `assertNotNull(userDb);` passes no problems, so it cant be that

Comment: @Joe Maher: is this an Android Test (run on device or emulator) or JUnit test run on pc?

Comment: @qmar i have amended my post with how im currently doing it on a device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked out how to access the entities when running tests on a device using the following:

```
public class UserDaoHelperTest extends ApplicationTestCase<Application> {

    private UserDao userDb;

    public UserDaoHelperTest() {
        super(Application.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void setUp(){

        DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper openHelper = new DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper(getContext(), null, null);
        SQLiteDatabase db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        DaoSession daoSession = new DaoMaster(db).newSession();
        userDb = daoSession.getUserDao();
    }
}
```